# Why does the CLR overflow an Int32.MaxValue -> Single -> Int32, where the JVM does not?

Tags: jvm, floating-point, clr, int

I ran into an unexpected result in round-tripping `Int32.MaxValue` into a `System.Single`:

```
Int32 i = Int32.MaxValue;
Single s = i;
Int32 c = (Int32)s;

Debug.WriteLine(i); // 2147483647
Debug.WriteLine(c); // -2147483648
```

I realized that it must be overflowing, since `Single` doesn't have enough bits in the significand to hold the `Int32` value, and it rounds up. When I changed the `conv.r4` to `conv.r4.ovf` in the IL, an `OverflowExcpetion` is thrown. Fair enough...

However, while I was investigating this issue, I compiled this code in java and ran it and got the following:

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
float s = (float)i;
int c = (int)s;

System.out.println(i);  // 2147483647
System.out.println(c);  // 2147483647
```

I don't know much about the JVM, but I wonder how it does this. It seems much less surprising, but how does it retain the extra digit after rounding to 2.14748365E9? Does it keep some kind of internal representation around and then replace it when casting back to `int`? Or does it just round down to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to avoid overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case is explicitly handled by [§5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3) of the Java Language Specification:

> A narrowing conversion of a
>   floating-point number to an integral
>   type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted
>      either to a long, if T is long, or to
>      an int, if T is byte, short, char, or
>      int, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the
>        first step of the conversion is an int
>        or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an
>        infinity, the floating-point value is
>        rounded to an integer value V,
>        rounding toward zero using IEEE 754
>        round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then
>        there are two cases:
>
>      - If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a
>          long, then the result of the first
>          step is the long value V.
>      - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int,
>          then the result of the first step is
>          the int value V.
>    - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>      - The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude
>          or negative infinity), and the result
>          of the first step is the smallest
>          representable value of type int or
>          long.
>      - **The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude
>          or positive infinity), and the result
>          of the first step is the largest
>          representable value of type int or
>          long.**

Comment: <obi_wan>Follow the link, Luke...</obi_wan>

Comment: Ah, how those edits make comments appear so different than when first posted.